# Overfull hbox with exam class on `\hrulefill`

Tags: exam

I'm working with the exam class using `pdflatex` and for some reason am getting an overfull `hbox` error on the following example presented in the documentation:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,final]{exam}

% AMS Packages

\usepackage{amsmath}

% TiKZ Packages

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}

% Font Settings

\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MyriadPro}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion,expansion,final,babel]{microtype}

% Headers and Footers

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader{CSCI 3660}{Exam 2}{Fall 2019}
\runningheader{CSCI 3660}{Exam 2, Page \thepage\ of \numpages}{Fall 2019}
\firstpagefooter{}{}{}
\runningfooter{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering Answer all of the questions below. The
        organization and neatness of your answers, as well as the legibility of
        your writing will count for $10\%$ of your grade.}}}
\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Name and section:\enspace\hrulefill}

\vspace{5mm}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Instructor’s name:\enspace\hrulefill}


\begin{questions}

  \question foo

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Specifically, the issue is with the two `hrulefill` commands right before the questions environment. Does anyone know how to remedy this?

Comment: they are starting a paragraph so indented but specified as full width so over full by \parindent  you could use \noindent`

Comment: Also, for future reference, when preparing a minimal example you can remove unnecessary packages like `MinionPro` and `MyriadPro` to make people's lives easier.

Comment: Sorry about that. I kept them since I thought the font packages might be messing something up.